# Select date with select tag

Tags: date, select

I know this question is stupid, but I could not do and did not find anything on the internet to help me.

```
<select type="date" name="date" class="date"> <option> Select </option> </select>
```

I have this tag, and i need to put the dates inside.. like:

```
SELECT
01/01/2014
02/01/2014
etc
```

If you can help me, I appreciate it.

Comment: Your question is how do we put dates in the select? Can you please clarify your question as to EXACTLY what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry.. yes, i want put dates in the select, but not manually.. i want create a calendar, but just with the lines..

Comment: From what start date to what end date? In what programming language? Can you update your question with this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select type="date" name="date" class="date"> 
  <option value=""> Select </option> 
  <option value="01/01/2014"> 01/01/2014</option> 
  <option value="01/01/2014"> 02/01/2014</option> 
</select>
```

more info here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: Can i not create a calendar with lines without putting the dates manually?

Comment: what is your backend? is it pure html ?

Answer (score 0):

Insert more `option` tags to `select` tag:

```
<select type="date" name="date" class="date">
<option> Select </option>
<option> 01/01/2014 </option>
<option> 02/01/2014 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can i not create a calendar with lines without putting the dates manually?

Comment: If you are using PHP, you can do that by `for` cycle. If it is a static html page, you can use JavaScript.

Or you can also use [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) from jquery UI.